# Ruby: String can't be coerced into Float (TypeError) on running tests

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a solution in Ruby that will return the exchange rate between `from_currency` and `to_currency` on `date` as a float. The rates are held in a JSON file.

The JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "2018-12-11": {
    "USD": 1.1379,
    "JPY": 128.75,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.845,
    "DKK": 7.4641,
    "GBP": 0.90228,
    "HUF": 323.4,
    "PLN": 4.2983,
  },
```

and so on with more currencies and dates. The JSON uses EUR as its base rate.

This is my first time using Ruby - and i've created the following to attempt this:

Part 1: currency_exchange.rb

```
require 'currency_exchange_calc.rb'
require 'date'

rate = CurrencyExchange.rate('date', 'from_currency', 'to_currency').to_s
```

Part 2: currency_exchange_calc.rb

```
require 'json' 

module CurrencyExchange
  @rates = JSON.parse(File.read('jsonfile.json'))

  def self.rate(date, from_currency, to_currency)
    rates = @rates[date]                     # get rates of given day
    from_to_eur =  1.0 / from_currency       # convert to EUR
    rate = 1 / from_currency * to_currency   # convert to target currency
  end
end
```

When i run part 2 on its own using: test.rb as a test example

```
require_relative 'currency_exchange_calc.rb'
require 'date'

target_date = Date.new(2018,12,11).to_s
puts "USD to GBP: #{CurrencyExchange.rate(target_date, 'USD', 'GBP')}"
puts "USD to JPY: #{CurrencyExchange.rate(target_date, 'PLN', 'CHF')}"
puts "DKK to CAD: #{CurrencyExchange.rate(target_date, 'PLN', 'CHF')}"
```

it works correctly.

However, when i bundle this and use the tests required for this exercise i recieve the error:

String can't be coerced into Float (TypeError)
On the lines:
from_to_eur =  1.0 / from_currency       # convert to EUR
rate = 1 / from_currency * to_currency   # convert to target currency

The tests are:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'currency_exchange'
require 'date'

class CurrencyExchangeTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
  end

  def test_non_base_currency_exchange_is_correct
    correct_rate = 1.2870493690602498
    assert_equal correct_rate, CurrencyExchange.rate(Date.new(2018,11,22), "GBP", "USD")
  end
```

I have tried adding "%.2f" % and .to_s.
However, I have had no luck, does anyone have any ideas/suggestions/reccomendations for a beginner?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - I copied a few lines so you could get the idea - I've updated it now, thanks for highlighting!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistake in your code. You send `from_currency` and `to_currency` as string but you are not fetching appropriate values for this currencies from `@rates` hash. So you need to revise you code like this:

```rb
require 'json' 

module CurrencyExchange
  @rates = JSON.parse(File.read('jsonfile.json'))

  def self.rate(date, from_currency, to_currency)
    rates = @rates[date]
    from_currency_rate = rates[from_currency]
    to_currency_rate = rates[to_currency]
    
    from_to_eur =  1.0 / from_currency_rate
    rate = 1 / from_currency_rate * to_currency_rate 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this info - however I am now getting the following error:

`rate': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    from_currency_rate = rates[from_currency]
`

I'm assuming that it means that there is no match when im pulling it from the hash?

Comment: its probably about your date format. it can't match the date with your json file so `rates = @rates[date]` returning nil